# Google Maps API v3 autocomplete text width

Tags: css, google-maps-api-3

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places-autocomplete#style_autocomplete describes how to deal with searchbox. However in the old maps version when using directions the suggestions would appear in full (so the text width would be wider than the actual box). We have not been able to find anyway to accomplish this and we are using the https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete?csw=1 code.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The autocomplete generates a div with a .pac-container class, you can add a CSS rule to it and add priority using the `!important` option.

In your CSS add:

```
.pac-container {
  width: 200px !important;
}
```

Replace 200px for the desired width. I believe that should do the job.

Comment: @user3249175, I'm glad it worked, if it's the answer to your question please consider accepting the it with the big check next to my answer. Thank you :)